# What is the better data structure to design a class for song play station with my requirement?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, framework-design

I have to come up with a Class and Data Structure Design for a "metric" system to determine the top song of a  * band..

The class should have Two Web Service calls

```
void play(String bandname, String songname);/*This method has to play song with the requested brandname and songname. Also have to keep track of the song payed count to support the below method.*/

String topSong(String bandname);/* This method has to play mostly played song under the requested brand*/

Sample inputs:
BrandName:"Lady Gaga", Song : "Pokerface";
BrandName:"Lady Gaga", Song : "Pokerface";
BrandName:"Lady Gaga", Song : "Alejandro";
BrandName:"Bruno Mars",Song : "Treasure";
```

Please advice!

Comment: Why is this tagged amazon?

Comment: @kmkaplan seems like OP is using amazon WS. :D

Comment: This is one of the amazon's phone interview question i faced

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to maintain a dictionary, where key is band name and value is a priority queue. Each object inside priority queue will have "song name" and "play count" attributes and priority queue needs to be sorted by "play count" attributes. Each time a song is played, increment it's play count and heapify the queue.

Doing the above is a bit complicated and based on programming languages, implementation approach might vary wildly. You shouldn't do this unless the number of songs of a band can be huge, which is pretty unlikely.

Anyway, that's practical implementation detail. The text book answer for questions like these is always priority queue.

Answer (score 0):

If kept in memory, this looks like a job for a hash table, associative array, or dictionary.  If kept in a persistent store, a database would be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need two storages.

1. A dictionnary that maps `bandname` to it's top `songname`. Let's call it `topBandSong`.
2. A dictionnary that maps `(bandname, songname)` to the number of times this song has been played. Let's call it `bandSongPopularity`.

With this `topSong` is pretty simple (leaving aside the case where nothing is known about the band yet):

```
Map<String, String> topBandSong = new HashMap();
String topSong(String bandname) {
    return topBandSong.get(bandname);
}
```

The `play` function has to update both maps. This is really easy:

```
Map<String, BigInteger> bandSongPopularity = new HashMap();
void play(String bandname, String songname) {
    /* First update bandSongPopularity */
    String k = bandname + "\000" + songname;
    BigInteger popularity = bandSongPopularity.get(k);
    if (popularity == null) {
        popularity = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    }
    else {
        popularity = popularity.add(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    }
    bandSongPopularity.put(k, popularity);
    /* then update topBandSong */
    String top = topSong(bandname);
    if (top == null) {
        topBandSong.put(bandname, songname);
    }
    else {
        String topK = bandname + "\000" + top;
        BigInteger topPopularity = bandSongPopularity.get(topK);
        /* topPopularity can not be NULL */
        if (popularity.compareTo(topPopularity) > 0) {
            topBandSong.put(bandname, songname);
        }
    }
    /* Finally really play this song. But this is left as an exercise ;-) */
}
```

The complexity is the one of the underlying dictionnary you choose, i.e. a tree or a hash.

Note that the code reserves character number 0.